# Dropping a new hybrid app into an existing worklight project and it can't find the dojo files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We're trying to unzip a new worklight hybrid app (built by a separate team) into an existing worklight project, but it can't find the dojo files for packaging, any ideas?  We have only included the app subdirectory in this zip file.

We're not using the dojo toolkit, we're using a locally packaged dojo subdirectory

For some reason the new application isn't picking up the dojo path we've specified in build-dojo.properties. Here's our build-dojo.properties information:

```
app.id=ACMWorkExecution
dojo.workspaceRoot=/AnywhereWorkManager/www
```

Any ideas of places we could debug?  We put some echo statements in the build-dojo.xml file to echo out the dojo.workspaceRoot but it didn't even appear to be called.

We're building the app using the app-builder ant task of worklight.

Answer (score 1):

We found out we had an invalid build-dojo.xml file that was causing this issue.  Replacing the build-dojo.xml file with a fresh one fixed it.